# Как проверить прекратил ли работу процесс?

Tags: python, tkinter

В то время пока работает процесс `sfc.exe` должен работать `Progress Bar` (кратко `pb`) в `tkinter`, а когда процесс `sfc.exe` прекратит свою работу, то `pb` должен остановиться и выскочить `MessageBox` с надписью **"Проверка завершена"**.

Сам код

```
def sfcscannow():
    os.system("sfc /scannow")

def prb():
    pb.pack(side="bottom")
    pb.start()  

def StartScan(event):
    mb.askyesno(title="Информация", message="Проверка начата")
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=prb)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=sfcscannow)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

Comment: Попробуйте сделать что-нибудь ниже `os.system`. Код тут похоже синхронный, поэтому после завершения команды код дальше будет выполняться. Попробуйте так: `from tkinter import messagebox` и ниже `os.system`
`messagebox.showinfo("Информация", "Проверка завершена")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Попробуйте сделать что-нибудь ниже os.system. Код тут похоже синхронный, поэтому после завершения команды код дальше будет выполняться. Попробуйте так: from tkinter import messagebox и ниже os.system messagebox.showinfo("Информация", "Проверка завершена")

Спасибо gil9red за ответ, хоть это был и комментарий